# What game is featured in this video?

Tags: game-identification

So I watched this video (and several like it) and he's playing a game in it:

***WARNING: VIDEO CONTAINS ADULT HUMOR***

At the bottom of the screen it says '*masterchiefslayer*' which I was hoping was the name of the game, however upon searching Google for 'master chief slayer' I get hits to Halo (which the person in the video also plays in other videos, leading me to believe that's his gamer tag).

What is the name of this game and is there a link for it?

It reminds me of a MUD version of Fargoal (just slightly).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is [NetHack](http://www.nethack.org/). See the [Wiki](http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/NetHack)

NetHack is quite a popular roguelike game, created in 1987 but the current version was released in 2003.

The game is a hack n slash kind of game but has a subtle humor and intellectual elements making it more popular with mathematicians, programmers, engineers and the like.

As @SLC mentioned; you can watch people playing it or play it yourself in real time using telnet or a browser version at alt.org/nethack

Comment: You can see the wiki at about 36-37 seconds in.

Comment: @Nick I knew it looked familiar. Thats why I asked, I couldn't place it but I knew I'd seen it. It was somethign I had played when it came out and then forgot it. Then I saw this video and couldn't recall the name. Didn't notice the screen shot, silly me.

Comment: The "11 years" should be expanded into created 1987 and current version roughly from 2003, to put things into perspective.

Comment: You can watch people playing it or play it yourself in real time using telnet or a browser version at http://alt.org/nethack/